# How to extract ClaimsPrincipal from AuthenticationStateProvider in Transient middleware service

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, middleware, claims-based-identity

I have a blazor server web application and a .NET Core worker process, these both use a common class for data access (generic unit of work / generic repository).

In the database I would like to log the user names that are inserting or editing records. To do this I want to inject a ClaimsPrincipal to the shared UoW and Repo classes).

So, I would like to be able to extract the current `ClaimsPrincipal` in a transient service via dependency injection.

For the worker I can inject a ClaimsPrincipal via the following code;

```
 public static IServiceCollection CreateWorkerClaimsPrincipal(this IServiceCollection services, string workerName) 
        {
            Claim workerNameClaim = new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", workerName);

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { workerNameClaim },
                "My-Worker-Authentication-Type", 
                "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "role");

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(s => principal);

            return services;
        }
```

This is working and meets my needs.

For the blazor server web application I need to do something similar.

I believe that the correct way to extract the `ClaimsPrincipal` is via the `AuthenticationStateProvider`, however this needs a call to an async method  `GetAuthenticationStateAsync`.

NOTE: I cannot user `IHttpContextAccessor` as this doesn't work with Azure App Service.

I want something like;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /// ...
    services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(); // I think I need to do something here?
    /// ...
}
```

So when I request a `ClaimsPrincipal` via dependency injection I want to return the user from;

```
var authState = await AUthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
return authState.User;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you use `ClaimsPrincipal` currently and how do you want to use so it doesn't work?

Comment: What flavor of Blazor do you use ?

Comment: @Alexander I am using the `ClaimsPrincipal` to log audit information regarding which users are performing which actions in my DB. All my DB actions are performed via a generic "UnitOfWork" class, and I'd like to inject the user information here, rather than having to pass it in from every calling service. I have both web and worker processes accessing the UoW class, so I am not able to inject `AuthenticationStateProvider` instead of `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Comment: @enet I am using Blazor server side.

Comment: I have added some more information on the context of the problem.

Comment: I cannot imagine why `IHttpContextAccessor` does not work when deploying the app on Azure. It's so just weird. Each request processing shares just one same context called `HttpContext`, no multithreading here. `HttpContext` is ***one place*** to store the User (after authentication), so if you create your own scoped service, it's just another place. Your solution seems to be fine as long as you know ***where*** to feed your scope service with a User (of course as soon as after authentication). All the subsequent code can consume it normally.

Comment: @KingKing yep, believe me I had worked really hard to create and test a scalable and well isolated application, and was in super smug mode as I deployed to Azure, then boom :-( I have read details on why this does not work , but its left me stumped...

Comment: I have a found a workable solution, but would appreciate any comments on the approach, particularly the **Async initialisation** which is unfamiliar to me. It feels risky. Is this safe?

Comment: Not to worry. This is safe, as you do nothing risky or adventurous... You're only assigning a constant value to the  AuthenticationStateProvider, and as long as the GetAuthenticationStateAsync is not called before you set the value...all is well

Comment: @KingKing - I found the explanation for _why_ this doesn't work.... "Additionally, again for security reasons, you must not use IHttpContextAccessor within Blazor apps. Blazor apps run outside of the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline. The HttpContext isn't guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor, nor is it guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app." taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-and-shared-state

Comment: @MarkCooper thanks for sharing, actually I've not had a chance to work with Blazer before.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the way, by working this through into a simple example for a SO post I have found a workable (I think) solution from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider

---

**NOTE:** I'm still not 100% sure if the *async init* pattern will always resolve the AuthenticationState before the Repository property is called, but its hanging together so far... Just beware of this if you choose to use this code.

---

I have changed the approach, and instead of trying to resolve `ClaimsPrincipal` via DI (because `AuthenticationStateProvider` is not available for a worker process), I have created a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` in the worker.

```
    public class WorkerAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly string _workerName;

        public WorkerAuthStateProvider(string workerName)
        {
            _workerName = workerName;
        }

        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _workerName),
            }, "My-Worker-Authentication-Type");

            ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
    }
```

and then register this in `configureServices` to resolve for instances of `AuthenticationStateProvider` in the worker program.cs file (also passing a custom worker process name, so I can use this on all my workers);

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, WorkerAuthStateProvider>(serviceProvider =>
{
   return new WorkerAuthStateProvider(Constants.Logging.RoleNames.MYWORKERNAME);
});
```

The `AuthenticationStateProvider` already works in the blazor web apps so this allows me to resolve this correctly, in the constructor for my **GenericUnitOfWork** pattern for data access on both Web and Workers, for example;

```
        private TDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger<TEntity> _logger;
        private GenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> _repository;
        private ClaimsPrincipal _user;
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;


        public GenericUnitOfWork(TDbContext context, ILogger<TEntity> logger, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _logger = logger;
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
            UserInit = InitUserAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Async initialisation pattern from https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html
        /// </summary>
        public Task UserInit { get; private set; }

        private async Task InitUserAsync()
        {
            var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            _user = authState.User;
        }

        public IGenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> Repository
        {
            get
            {
                if (_repository == null)
                {
                    // when accessing the repository, we are expecting to pass the current application claims principal
                    // however the ClaimsPrincipal is resolved using an Async method from the AuthenticationStateProvider.
                    // In the event that the Async method has not yet completed we need to throw an exception so we can determine
                    // if a further async code fix is required.
                    if (_user == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Async ClaimsPrincipal has not been loaded from the AuthenticationStateProvider");
                    }

                    _repository = new GenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext>(_dbContext, _logger, _user);
                   
                }
                return _repository;
            }
        }
```